# RTCPeerConnection is creating invalid SDP with createOffer function

Tags: react-native, webrtc-android

Im using 1.87.3 react-native-webrtc and react-native 0.64.3 Android 11. Im using this function for createOffer but its produces an incomplete sdp. When i createOffer from web side client its success, rnative and web side can communicate. But when i try to createoffer from React native side its creating invalid sdp. Is there any idea?

`peer.createOffer().then(desc => { console.log(desc); peer.setLocalDescription(desc).then(() => { //do something }); });`

**This is created SDP by CreateOffer function** = "v=0 ↵o=- 7968195522823789820 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1 ↵s=- ↵t=0 0 ↵a=msid-semantic: WMS ↵"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i should have to call addStream function before creating an offer.